# Can i update core file while magento is set to production mode?

Tags: magento2, optimization

I'm aware, magento has three types of modes. On that, the production mode is speed compared to other modes. So I changed my magento site to production mode for better speed and optimization. Do i need to change the mode from production to developer in order to update the core file or i can update it even in the production mode?

Because it's a big headache each time switch the mode for any update. Please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "update the core file"? You should never be modifying core files directly. Learn to use Magento's module system and do things right, it will save you a lot of headaches.

The intended workflow is to leave your production site in production mode. You should have a separate copy of the site and codebase explicitly for development purposes. You can set that dev site to developer mode for the faster workflow. When you have changes ready to take live, copy the changes across (preferably using version control/a deployment process), then upgrade and recompile your production site.

Answer (score 0):

**Default:**

Enables you to deploy the Magento application on a single server without changing any settings. However, default mode is not optimized for production.

To deploy the Magento application on more than one server or to optimize it for production, change to one of the other modes.

Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static directory
Exceptions are not displayed to the user; instead, exceptions are written to log files.
Hides custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers

**Developer:**

Intended for development only, this mode:

Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static directory
Provides verbose logging
Enables automatic code compilation
Enables enhanced debugging
Shows custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers
Results in the slowest performance (because of the preceding)
Magento Commerce (Cloud) supports production mode only.

**Production:**

Intended for deployment on a production system, this mode:

Does not show exceptions to the user (exceptions are written to logs only).
Serves static view files from cache only.
Prevents automatic code file compilation. New or updated files are not written to the file system.
Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in Magento Admin.

For more information visit [site](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html).